# Where to check for an Active flag in aspnet Identity 2.1.0 when signing in a user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net Identity 2.1.0 and I added an "Active" property to my ApplicationUser.

If I set the Active property to false I want the user to be unable to sign in -regardless of whether they signed in with a username and password or with an external login.

I would also like users with the "remember me" option selected to be unable to login if their active bit flips to false, and anytime the identity is regenerated like in IdentityUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync() it should check the user's active status.

Where should logic such as this go? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @spender I don't think that's really relevant to the question. It might be chat-worthy.

Comment: @RowanFreeman It's a comment to the sentence 'I would also like users with the "remember me" option selected to be unable to login'. It seems like a broken experience to even offer it, because in this case it should be labelled "prevent me from logging in". I shouldn't be chastised for bringing this up. These are the comments, after all.

Comment: The "Remember Me" feature in the OPs case works like any other. The  OP is indicating that, if the user is marked as *inactive* then they should be forcibly logged out, even if they have indicated "Remember Me". I don't see why it's relevant to ask *why* the OP has implemented a "Remember Me" feature.

Comment: Yes -like Rowan explained. My reason for mentioning it is just to point out that I would like to avoid placing code in the controller with the sign-in method because it doesn't cover every scenario.

Comment: There is an option, you could lock the user's depending on there login attempts. You could use that option for your active or inactive requirements.